# Inner joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join an additional table to my query and I ran into this error:

> Not unique table/alias: 'events'

It happened when I added:

```
events INNER JOIN party_types
ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
```

To my code which now looks like this:

```
SELECT
    events.EVENT_NAME, events.start_datetime, events.end_datetime, events.VENUE_LOCATION, events.PARTY_TYPE, events.IMAGE_URL, 
    venues.VENUE_NAME, 
    party_types.PARTYTYPE
FROM
    events INNER JOIN venues 
    events INNER JOIN party_types
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
    ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
WHERE
    start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' and end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED
```

Any ideas why this happened? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not valid syntax. It's being interpreted as follows:

```
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues AS events
INNER JOIN party_types
```

The second `events` is being interpreted as an alias for the `venues` table. The `AS` is optional.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    events.start_datetime,
    events.end_datetime,
    events.VENUE_LOCATION,
    events.PARTY_TYPE,
    events.IMAGE_URL, 
    venues.VENUE_NAME, 
    party_types.PARTYTYPE
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues 
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
INNER JOIN party_types
    ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
```